# Проигрывание анимации

Tags: android, анимация, спрайт

Здравствуйте! Никто не подскажет, как можно проиграть спрайт от начала и до конца? Спрайт состоит из 20 кадров, вот мне нужно проиграть эти 20 кадров и все. как?

**UPD:**
Проигрываю анимацию на Canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если API предусматривает повторы, то должен явно передаваться параметр, определяющий их количество.

[Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property)

> **android:repeatCount**
>
> int. How many times to repeat an animation. Set to "-1" to infinitely repeat or to a positive integer. For example, a value of "1" means that the animation is repeated once after the initial run of the animation, so the animation plays a total of two times. The default value is "0", which means no repetition.
>
> int. Положительное целое число. Определяет, сколько раз повторять анимацию. Установите в "-1", чтобы повторять бесконечно. Например, значение "1" означает, что анимация повторяется после первого запуска анимации, так что анимация играет два раза. По умолчанию значение "0", что означает отсутствие повторений.

Comment: Есть другие предложения? Мне нужно проиграть спрайт от начала и до конца. Спрайт состоит из 20 кадров, вот мне нужно проиграть эти 20 кадров и все.